# Can I search for channels which contain at least one video?

Tags: youtube-api

I am searching for channels against the YouTube API v3:

```
/search?part=id&type=channel&q=searchquery
```

Problem: It also returns channels which contain zero (0) videos.

I can see two possible approaches:

1. Use the `&order=videoCount` parameter, which sorts DESC the returned channels by the number of videos they contain.
2. Run a second query to search for videos in each channel, limit `&maxResults=1` the returned amount of videos to one, and parse the result.

I don't want to take approach 1, as it changes the default `&order=relevance`, which I believe is fine-tuned by YouTube to return the most relevant channels first [still, the result may contain channels without videos, which makes YouTube's algorithm for calculating relevance questionable].

Approach 2 causes a lot of additional load, so it also isn't something that I'd want to do.

Is there a way to solve this in an elegant way that I don't see right now?

Answer (score 0):

Approach 2 makes sense and assuming you'll use paging, you can run the second query as you need, instead of trying to run the query against the whole result set. That should be fine.